# [Azure][Application Insights agent for Java]Failed to create InProcessTelemetryChannel, null

Tags: java, apache, azure, tomcat6, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to set-up application insights for an running apache tomcat application.

I have followed every step in this tutorial of microsoft: [enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-live)
But when I start it, I'm getting the following error message.

```
ERROR 02-01-2017 21:50, 15: Failed to create com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannel, null
```

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 | Jan 02, 2017 9:50:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 | SEVERE: Exception starting filter ApplicationInsightsWebFilter
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:493)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:105)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.ApacheSender43.(ApacheSender43.java:45)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.ApacheSenderFactory.create(ApacheSenderFactory.java:40)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.TransmissionNetworkOutput.(TransmissionNetworkOutput.java:95)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.channel.common.TransmissionNetworkOutput.create(TransmissionNetworkOutput.java:85)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannelFactory.create(InProcessTelemetryChannelFactory.java:41)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannel.initialize(InProcessTelemetryChannel.java:263)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.concrete.inprocess.InProcessTelemetryChannel.(InProcessTelemetryChannel.java:147)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.setChannel(TelemetryConfigurationFactory.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.internal.config.TelemetryConfigurationFactory.initialize(TelemetryConfigurationFactory.java:102)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration.getActive(TelemetryConfiguration.java:74)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.microsoft.applicationinsights.web.internal.WebRequestTrackingFilter.init(WebRequestTrackingFilter.java:127)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1079)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1002)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:506)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.servoy.j2db.server.main.WebServer.startWebServer(WebServer.java:30)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.servoy.j2db.server.main.ApplicationServer.startWebServer(ApplicationServer.java:491)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2017/01/02 21:50:53 |   at com.servoy.j2db.server.main.ApplicationServer.main(ApplicationServer.java:286)

It mentions that the configuration file has been found succesfully.
Also I have setup the ApplicationInsights.xml just as describred in the tutorial.

I'm lost here!
Did someone ever encounter the same problem? Or does someone know what I am doing wrong here?

This is the current setup version of tomcat:
[Screenshot of version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSi7l.png)

Thanks!

Comment: I reviewed your refered tutorial which seems to be not complete for those xml configuration files. Please try to refer to [the tutorial within `en-us`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-live) to reconfigure & run again. Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The class ApplicationInsightsWebFilter is not found: NoClassDefFoundError.

Can you please make sure that all ApplicationInights jars are present in the class path? Try to put them in your WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: I have downloaded the zip from: https://aijavasdk.blob.core.windows.net/sdk/sdk.html.
And all the files were extracted to the lib folder.

Comment: OK. But this error means that the class is not found in runtime. You need to make sure that the applicationinsights-web jar is visible.

Comment: That's problably the problem then. I have no clue how to do that :)

Comment: Try put all jars (including CORE and WEB) in the WEB-INF/lib folder and then restart Tomcat